# How does IBM's 53-bit quantum computer compare to classical ones for cryptanalytic tasks?

Tags: quantum-cryptanalysis, quantum-computing

IBM just [announced](https://newsroom.ibm.com/2019-09-18-IBM-Opens-Quantum-Computation-Center-in-New-York-Brings-Worlds-Largest-Fleet-of-Quantum-Computing-Systems-Online-Unveils-New-53-Qubit-Quantum-System-for-Broad-Use) *"a new 53-qubit quantum computer"*.

How does it compare to classical computers, performance-wise, for cryptanalytic tasks? E.g. finding a 48- or 64-bit value whose SHA-256 has a certain value (edit: or factoring the product of two distinct primes, or computing some discrete logarithm).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> How does it compare to classical computers, performance-wise, for cryptanalytic tasks?

Not at all - IBM's quantum computer cannot perform any nontrivial cryptanalytic task.

For one, 53 physical qubits far too few to do anything interesting; for example, implementing SHA-256 would take thousands of logical qubits.

For another, the qubits are not even close to be reliable enough.  The IBM quantum computer cannot do any quantum error correction - this means that, as it performs operations on the qubits, the errors pile up.  Any interesting cryptanalytic task requires us to perform millions (or more) of quantum operations; even a slight amount of error accumulation would overwhelm any result.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98911/discussion-on-answer-by-poncho-how-does-ibms-53-bit-quantum-computer-compare-to).