# After Google's breakthrough: When will quantum computers break today's encryption?

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography

Google [announced](https://www.sciencenews.org/article/google-quantum-computer-supremacy-claim) a breakthrough on the way to building usable and useful quantum computers.

Since I'm not a cryptographer, I wanted to ask when quantum computers will be able to break the crypto algorithms used today and whether this breakthrough has significantly changed the predictions.

Also, when will good post-quantum crypto libraries be available so that programmers can slowly begin replacing currently used crypto with post-quantum cryptography or go with a hybrid solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does IBM's 53-bit quantum computer compare to classical ones for cryptanalytic tasks?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/74395/18298)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Since I'm not a cryptographer, I wanted to ask when quantum computers will be able to break the crypto algorithms used today and whether this breakthrough has significantly changed the predictions.

**No, despite being [on the front page of *Nature*](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-019-1666-5), Google's result has no impact on cryptography for the foreseeable future.**

The news about the (rather regrettable) term ‘quantum supremacy’ means that **Google claims to have demonstrated ‘solving’ *some* problem on a quantum computer faster than anyone has been able to solve that problem on a classical computer.**  In one sense, this is a remarkable achievement, because nobody had been able to do it before.  In another sense, it is the *tiniest achievement imaginable*: after decades of research, they *found a problem*, among all possible computational problems one might imagine whether or not solving it has any utility whatsoever, that they were able to demonstrate a quantum computer is better at than a classical computer.  (Maybe [‘quantum non-uselessness’ would be a better term than ‘quantum supremacy’](https://medium.com/@emma.m.mckay/why-we-need-to-get-over-quantum-supremacy-619ddf67ae72), or perhaps ‘quantum non-futility’ since the problem they found is not terribly useful itself.)

The ‘problem’, in this case, is, given a random quantum circuit of about 50 qubits chosen by a challenger, to apply it on an all-zero initial state, and measure the result in the $\{0,1\}$ basis.  A choice of quantum circuit gives rise to a probability distribution on the outputs of this procedure—run the circuit on all zero inputs, measure the result in the $\{0,1\}$ basis—and nobody has shown a way to sample from this distribution as efficiently on a classical computer.  The results are then *verified* by statistical tests computed using classical simulation with about $2^{50}$ computations (which puts a bit of a damper on the prospect of verifying results like these on, say, 100-qubit circuits).

**What Google has *not* demonstrated is anything that is useful for running quantum circuits like Grover's algorithm or Shor's algorithm,** which requires substantially larger numbers of qubits and error correction at a scale we're nowhere near.  For more details, see [Scott Aaronson's Supreme Quantum Supremacy FAQ](https://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/?p=4317).

To the best of my knowledge, no quantum computer has ever factored a number larger than 21 using Shor's algorithm, and there's no reason to suspect that other quantum factoring methods will meaningfully scale; see [fgrieu's past answer on quantum factoring records](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/59796) (which I hope he will keep updated if the literature changes so I don't have to!).  [Scott Aaronson estimates](https://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/?p=4317#comment-1820315) that if configured to run Shor's algorithm, Google's quantum computer could maybe manage factoring a number ‘up to the hundreds, depending on how much precompilation and other classical trickery was allowed’

> Also, when will good post-quantum crypto libraries be available so that programmers can slowly begin replacing currently used crypto with post-quantum cryptography or go with a hybrid solution?

Symmetric-key cryptography is not seriously threatened by quantum computers as long as you already meet a classical 128-bit security level by using ≫128-bit keys like 256-bit keys, which you're already doing, right?

There is an ongoing competition, [NIST PQC](https://nist.gov/pqcrypto), to settle on candidates for standardization of post-quantum public-key cryptography—encryption, key agreement, and signatures.  Aside from the NIST PQC candidates' reference implementations, available via the NIST PQC web site and in [SUPERCOP](https://bench.cr.yp.to/supercop.html), there are also some prototype libraries of post-quantum cryptography candidates, such as [liboqs (open quantum safe)](https://openquantumsafe.org), and experiments in deployment in protocols such as [SSH](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/858) and [TLS](https://www.imperialviolet.org/2018/12/12/cecpq2.html).

Answer (score 1):

It's still probably going to be a while.  That's for 53 qubits.  For proper error handling they'd probably need somewhere between 2,500 and 3,000 qubits to break 2,048 bit RSA.

As for libraries, [NIST is working on standardizing post quantum algos now](https://csrc.nist.gov/Projects/Post-Quantum-Cryptography/Workshops-and-Timeline).  They think they'll have standards ready sometime between 2022 and 2024.  Decent implementations will probably be ready concurrent with the standard and good implementations a year or two later.  Absent some significant breakthrough, the algorithms and libraries should be ready before they're needed.

Comment: This answer is a little optimistic from the quantum side of things, pessimistic from the cryptography side of things.  Absent a breakthrough in error-correction technology, it would require millions of physical qubits of the sort in Google's reported quantum computer to factor a typical RSA modulus.